# Android ListView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, listactivity

I am trying to create a list of items which contains an image and some description for the image in each individual. After which, the list will be place in a `fragment` inside the application. Can anyone guide me to create it? I am not too sure how can I do it without the `ListActivity`.

Answer (score 42):

It seems like your Fragment should subclass [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) (not ListActivity). `onCreateView()` from ListFragment will return a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) you can then populate.

Here's more information on populating lists from the developer guide: [Hello, ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then mark as the answer and post a new question for your new problem that someone can help you with.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a code snippet to help you display ListView in a fragment.:

```
public class MessagesFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container,
            false);

    String[] values = new String[] { "Message1", "Message2", "Message3" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

And, this is how the xml would look like:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

If you do not use 'list' as ID or do not include a ListView into your layout, the application crashes once you try to display the activity or the fragment.

Reference: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments

Comment: make sure to not wrap_content in ListView for layout_height, instead fill_parent or match_parent.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview