# Issue using another ListView as header in my current ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I thought I would have trouble adding a ListView as a header to an existing ListView because both have scroller container. But that part works fine, the header ListView gets automatically scrolled with the parent ListView.

The only issue I have is that the ListView in the header always shows just one element even though its adapter dataset contains more than one element. I tried setting its layout parameters (height to WRAP_CONTENT) programatically but I couldn't fix this.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this behavior (only one visible element from the header list) ?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap content height does't work on list view. If you want. Try to set fix height for your listview(header).
And keep in mind, nested listview maybe a bad idea.

Related issue from here i guess as per [K_anas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview).