# Scroll up does not work with SwipeRefreshLayout in Listview

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I want to implement scroll to refresh functionality with a listView. Also there are other view elements in the same layout file which are displayed if the list is empty. Here is my layout file. The problem is that when I scroll down and then try to scroll up, instead of scrolling all the way to the top and then refreshing it just refreshes there and scroll up is not working.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/inbox_empty" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noEventsText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/noEventsIcon" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="@color/dividerOnBlack" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is my onScroll method.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount) {
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; } 
    }

    // If it's still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        currentPage++;
    }

    // If reverse then the firstVisibleItem is calculated wrong
    if (reverse) {
        firstVisibleItem = totalItemCount - firstVisibleItem;
    }
    // If it isn't currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 59):

In order for SwipeRefreshLayout to work, it needs to be the direct parent of your ListView, and the ListView should be the first active child view of the SwipeRefreshLayout.

The documentation for SwipeRefreshLayout says that the ListView should be the only child, but it is okay if it has more than one child as long as the ListView is first.  This means, for instance, that SwipeRefreshLayout will work fine if you are using an adapter with a view for "empty".  For example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NearbyJobsActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

If you can manage this sort of layout, then SwipeRefreshLayout will work fine and you won't need any of the workarounds listed in other answers.

My own problem was that that I was loading my ListView as a Fragment, so I actually had:

```
<SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <FrameLayout>           )
         <ListView/>        \ fragment
         <TextView/>        /
    </FrameLayout>          )

</SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

So the SwipeRefreshLayout was choosing the FrameLayout as it's "target" and its default `canChildScrollUp()` implementation was always returning false.  Once I moved the SwipeRefreshLayout inside the Fragment, everything started working correctly.

```
<FrameLayout>

    <SwipeRefreshLayout>    )
         <ListView/>        \ fragment
         <TextView/>        /
    </SwipeRefreshLayout>   )

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem and solved it:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (listView.getChildAt(0) != null) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Good solution !

Comment: this is the best solution ever. very simple snippet

Comment: Thanks Only one that worked since using Default List had to find it by looking for `android.R.id.list`

Comment: Should be the accepted answer! Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Great Man it solved my problem with Gridview thanks a lot dear

Answer (score 28):

Create a layout like this one.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/guides_no_results"
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/guides_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you use this as-is, everytime you scroll up in that view, the SwipeRefreshLayout fires and updates, making your app unable to scroll up in a list.

The trick here is to wire the OnScrollListener from the ListView manually. You just check if the first row being shown matches the first top-most position, and then enable the SwipeRefreshLayout. Otherwise, disable it.

```
guidesList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener()
{  
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
    {
        int topRowVerticalPosition = (guidesList == null || guidesList.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : guidesList.getChildAt(0).getTop();
        swipeContainer.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
    }
});
```

With this little snippet now it works perfectly.

Happy coding!

Source - http://nlopez.io/swiperefreshlayout-with-listview-done-right/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg the flag was for the original post with link only answer, which has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @Zielu Well, so we can all delete the unnecessary comments ;)

Comment: It works, but i have different problem in this. When the first row in the list have the size greater than the parent (say its a text view with very long text) then it don't show any other row.

Comment: This works for me, but it's not ideal needing a reference to your `Activity`'s `SwipeRefreshLayout` if you're implementing this in a fragment.

Answer (score 11):

Make your own implementation of SwipeRefreshLayout and override the canChildScrollUp in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
if (scrollView != null)
    return scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1);

return false;
}
```

just replace with any subclass of ScrollView.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem where the child of my `SwipeRefreshLayout` was a `FrameLayout` which had a `TextView` and `ListView` as children and when I scrolled up on the `ListView` it would try to do a refresh.

I fixed it by using a custom `FrameLayout`which overrides the `canScrollVertically()` method

package com.wi.director.ui.common;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

/**
 * Created by devansh on 9/22/15.
 */
public class FrameLayoutForSwipeRefresh extends FrameLayout {

    public FrameLayoutForSwipeRefresh(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FrameLayoutForSwipeRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FrameLayoutForSwipeRefresh(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
        if (super.canScrollVertically(direction)) {
            return true;
        }

        int cc = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < cc; i++) {
            if (getChildAt(i).canScrollVertically(direction)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change my fragment layout slightly to match your's (well, without the TextView) for this to work, but it does work a treat. A nice, clean solution - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler just set `SwipeRefreshLayout` enabled **if** `firstVisibleItem` or disabled if not:

```
yourList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override 
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        yourSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `RecyclerView` or `ListView` is not the direct child of `SwipeRefreshLayout` then this issue occurs.

Simplest solution is to provide `OnChildScrollUpCallback` implementation and return the results appropriately. In Kotlin code below, `refreshLayout` is `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `recyclerView` is `RecyclerView` as can be seen in `xml` layout code as well.

```
refreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback(object : SwipeRefreshLayout.OnChildScrollUpCallback {
  override fun canChildScrollUp(parent: SwipeRefreshLayout, child: View?): Boolean {
    if (recyclerView != null) {
      return recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)
    }
    return false
  }
})
```

While `xml` layout is something like this,

```
 <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
    ...
    lots of other views i.e TextView, ImageView, MotionLayout
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView".../>
       
    ...
    ...
    ...
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

### My Gridview Start Working with Swipefreshlayout

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)

        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (gridView.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                mrefreshlayout.setEnabled(gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && gridView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
            }

         }


       });
```

### layout in xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefreshlayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <GridView
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nofieldtv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adlayout"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we want to scroll something scrollable. We can put all views in ScrollView.

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

But scrolling ListView may require some modifications - [wrap_content ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31674843/6049708)

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:-**

```
 recyclerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            int topRowVerticalPosition = (binding.rvMessageList == null || binding.rvMessageList.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : binding.rvMessageList.getChildAt(0).getTop();
            swipeRefresh.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`@the_dani` has given right answer but it was for `listview` so here I give you solution for `recylerview` onscroll conflict with swipe refresh layout. For `Recyclerview` you have to use `LayoutManager` for get `first visible item`.

```
 rvStaggered.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                  if (recyclerView.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                    swipeMain.setEnabled(
                            linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0
                                    && recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
                }
            }

});
```

Answer (score -1):

For Xamarin I had the same issue (Scroll up does not work with `SwipeRefreshLayout` in `ListView`) and implemented it this way.

```
public void OnScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

}

public void OnScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, [GeneratedEnum]ScrollState scrollState) {
    if (listView.GetChildAt(0) != null) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.Enabled = listView.FirstVisiblePosition == 0 && listView.GetChildAt(0).Top == 0;
    }
}
```