# Android SwipeRefreshLayout with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, swiperefreshlayout

Here is my code setup:

Currently I have a Main Activity which then creates a spawns a fragment with `getSupportFragmentManager()`. The Fragment contains a `RecyclerView` (for a card view) as defined in the xml below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the layout of my main activity:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The main activity instantiates the fragment which then creates its own `RecyclerView, LinearLayoutManager, and Adapter` without any connections to the main activity.

The main activity creates the SwipeRefreshLayout as seen in the xml above.

The problem I have is the when I scroll up in my activity, once the list cannot scroll any further up the refresh indicator pulls down if I keep swiping down and refreshes. **I don't want the indicator to pull down until I release the current touch and pull down again.**

Since I cannot directly access the recycler view from my activity to add an OnScrollListener and enable and disable the SwipeRefreshLayout programmatically, how should I go about solving this?

All answers appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since I cannot directly access the recycler view from my activity to
>   add an OnScrollListener and enable and disable the SwipeRefreshLayout
>   programmatically, how should I go about solving this?

Yes, you can!

First implement [**RecyclerView.OnScrollListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html) so that your fragment can listen to scroll events. To do so you have to subclass `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`: https://gist.github.com/ArtworkAD/ae6241d60282a54adfa22d28cddb48ae

The next step is to delegate the scroll events to the hosting activity to make changes to the swipe layout. Your fragment may have following additions:

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment implements OnScrollStateListener {

    public interface ScrollEventListener {
        void onScroll(int dx, int dy)
        void onScrollStateChanged(int state)
    }

    ScrollEventListener scrollEventListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Give the recycler view a scroll listener
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new DefaultRecycleViewScrollListener(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        // delegate the event to the listener
        scrollEventListener.onScrollStateChanged(newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
        // delegate the event to the listener
        scrollEventListener.onScrolled(dx, dy);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        // activity should implement the interface
        if (context instanceof ScrollEventListener) {
          scrollEventListener = (ScrollEventListener) context;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to implement `ScrollEventListener` in your activity to receive scroll events.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity implements SomeFragment.ScrollEventListener {

     @Override
     public void onScroll(int dx, int dy) {
         // access swipe layout here
     }

     @Override
     public void void onScrollStateChanged(int state){
         if (state == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
             // disable swipe
         } else {
             // enable
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: it did work but I am getting the speed of the scroll change, how can I make it so that the refresh indicator should not show until a new touch happens.

Comment: @skyguy126 not speed but the change in coordinates. Make use of onScrollStateChanged https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, int). I changed the code and the gist.

Comment: almost there... calling this `this.swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);` seems to have no effect on the refresh. Any idea what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it is called? What do you mean with "no effect"? setEnabled(false) should disable the gesture.

Comment: Yes it is being called I set up some logging and I can see the log messages coming up. Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/skyguy126/a4d8b842e6406a98a03a6682cbe1dbcc No "effect" as in the gesture still works

Comment: @skyguy126 If the gesture still works, setEnabled(false) should not have been called.  Maybe you have this problem due to the fact that the list view is not a direct child of swipe layout, but I am not sure, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270171/scroll-up-does-not-work-with-swiperefreshlayout-in-listview

Comment: I think `setEnabled` is not updating the layout until I release the scroll. Maybe it is a different issue, but thanks for your help so far!