# Only refresh screen when top of list view (Android Studio)

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout

I have this SwipeRefreshLayout XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    tools:context="com.tag.instagramdemo.example.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background1">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/lvRelationShip2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvRelationShip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRowFive"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:maxWidth="40dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:text="Click To View"
                android:textSize="26dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="40dp"
                android:maxWidth="40dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow2" />

        </TableRow>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:contextClickable="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/text"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/text"
            design:menu="@menu/menu_main" />

    </TableLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Notice that I have this ListView with the ID: lvRelationShip.

In this SwipeRefresh XML file, I want the action of refreshing only to trigger when I scroll to the top of the ListView.

**Problem:** In the ListView when I scroll down to see other items in the list everything is fine, but when I scroll up to see previous Items, the page just refreshes. I want the list to only refresh when I scroll up at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Make your ListView a direct child of your RefreshView and also the first child. It believes that it has reached the top probably since there are other elements at the top of your XML

```
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
tools:context="com.tag.instagramdemo.example.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvRelationShip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>
```

...

I am writing this on my phone. Excuse the formatting errors. Notice I removed the two layout tags from the top, that is how you will require your layout to be, the list is a direct child and the first element.

Comment: I am new, how would I go apon doing this?

Comment: I am confused, what have you changed?

Comment: The way programming works is from the top down. Notice the first thing that comes after the refreshlayout  is your ListView that you want to refresh. It must be that way

Comment: Yes, you will have to re-order your View

Comment: Is there anyway I can keep the EditText at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Observe scroll position of list and disable SwipeRefreshLayout accordingly, This works for me

```
 //SwipeRefreshLayout refresh-only-when-at-the-top

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener =
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged() {
                    if (listView.getScrollY() == 0)
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                    else
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If `RecyclerView` or `ListView` is not the direct child of `SwipeRefreshLayout` then this issue occurs.

Simplest solution is to provide `OnChildScrollUpCallback` implementation and return the results appropriately. In Kotlin code below, `refreshLayout` is `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `recyclerView` is `RecyclerView` as can be seen in `xml` layout code as well.

```
refreshLayout.setOnChildScrollUpCallback(object : SwipeRefreshLayout.OnChildScrollUpCallback {
  override fun canChildScrollUp(parent: SwipeRefreshLayout, child: View?): Boolean {
    if (recyclerView != null) {
      return recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)
    }
    return false
  }
})
```

While `xml` layout is something like this,

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh".../>
    ...
    lots of other views i.e TextView, ImageView, MotionLayout
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recyclerView".../>
       
    ...
    ...
    ...
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

This is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016539/4931857).