# Android ListView Scroll down forces Pull To Refresh

Tags: android, listview, scroll, fragment, swiperefreshlayout

In my `Activity`, I have a `FrameLayout` inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout`, like this:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/filter_list_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I replace the `FrameLayout` with a `Fragment` which contains a `ListView`, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:divider="#d3d3d3"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

The problem that when I scroll down, the `ListView` doesn't scroll. Instead, the Pull to Refresh indicator is launched.

Any ideas? I know I could set a `OnScrollListener` in the `ListView` but I cannot access the `SwipeRefreshLayout` from the `Fragment` that contains the `ListView`.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: if you are in the activity you could easily access any view that is inside it "even it's inside the fragment" so i suggest to set the onPullRefresh of the swipe layout inside the activity then do what ever you want inside it
note that I suggest to use this instead
https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout

Comment: Take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35779571/2274847). I hope it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following parameter -

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: to the `ListView`?