# Set <fragment> height according to wrap it's content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity which contains text and a fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="bla.HomeActivity">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="A Text"
                android:id="@+id/home_text_view"/>
            <fragment
                android:name="bla.CalendarAgendaFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cf"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calendar_agenda" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment only contains a ListView which is filled dynamically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calendar_agenda_listview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The onCreateView method of the fragment looks like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar_agenda, container, false);

    agenda_dates = new ArrayList<CalendarDate>();
    agenda_dates.add(new CalendarDate("10.10.2015", "Kuchen backen"));
    agenda_dates.add(new CalendarDate("10.10.2015", "Fenster putzen"));

    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendar_agenda_listview);
    adapter = new AgendaAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.calendar_agenda_listview_item, agenda_dates);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
```

The code works and both CalendarDates are added to the fragment.

**The problem is that the fragment is only about 40dp high and so only the first ListView item is shown. I can only see the second item by inline scrolling inside of the list view.** How can I set the fragment's hight according to it's content?

Comment: The code is incomplete above, there is Scrollview, +1 LinearLayout in first xml? What are orientatioins of linear layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the height programatically, as seen [here](http://blog.lovelyhq.com/setting-listview-height-depending-on-the-items/)

Function:

```
public static boolean setListViewHeightBasedOnItems(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter != null) {

        int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

        // Get total height of all items.
        int totalItemsHeight = 0;
        for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems, itemPos++) {
            View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
            item.measure(0, 0);
            totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        // Get total height of all item dividers.
        int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() * 
                (numberOfItems - 1);

        // Set list height.
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: The link is die now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ListView doesn't work correctly with wrap_content.
See this question about it:
[Android: wrap_content is not working with ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview)

You should change the size of your ListView programmatically, as Rafael suggested.