# using com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView library how to set wrap content programatically

Tags: android, listview

I have a linear layout in xml with vertical orientation.

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutRoot = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listViewCompareLinear);
```

I used `com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView` library for horizontal `ListView` scroll. I need to call a no. of the horizontal scroll view programatically and add it to linear layout above (since it is dynamic, i cannot use through xml).

I did the following:

```
for (int k = 0; k < selectBike.size(); k++) {
    listView = new HorizontalListView(this, null);
    linearLayoutRoot.addView(listView);
}
```

But what happen is it displays only first `HorizontalListView` since i think it is set to match parent by default. I set the background color to the `HorizontalListView` and whole device screen is covered with that color. So setting it to `wrap_content` might solve the problem...

How to set the width to wrap content programmatically?

whole xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/horizontalListViewRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.bajaj.pulsar.pulsar.CompareListView">


    //it contains listViews dynamically
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listViewCompareLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/compare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="100dp"
    android:text="Compare" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

```
 listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));
```

Comment: try with constant height in it

Comment: if i set height, i can see other listviews as well. listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200)); But i want to wrap the content of listView

Comment: so now you have to set height appropriate to all devices . width can be match parent as I have changed in my answer.

Comment: ok thanks anyway... i wonder why wrap content doesnt work here. But setting the constant height may have problems in different devices.

Comment: do you set any background image to your horizontal list view?

Comment: yes i used adapters and it has checkbox with bg image with height and width equal to (device width / 5)

Comment: I dont think it is causing any issue . I mean background to Listview.

Comment: nope but the list view is under relativelayout in xml which has bg image

Comment: i have updated the whole xml in above question. I have a linearLayout which contains list view dynamically and a button in the bottom of the parent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview check this