# listView extends on program start

Tags: android, listview

I set my ListView in Android Studio like this:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

and attached it to the bottom of the screen. But if I run the app, the ListView extends and fills the entire screen.

Comment: put your layout xml completly

Comment: Post the entire activity layout

Comment: check the second answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295080/android-wrap-content-is-not-working-with-listview

Comment: `android:layout_height="200dp"` and 
    `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` both will not work together.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: I want it to fill about the half of the screen, but stay at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `LinearLayout` insted of `RelativeLayout` in your `.xml` file. Use `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I am using RelativeLayout.
I also noticed, that if I add some Items to the ListView and then scroll in there, the ListView gets back to its defined place.
Just if i click in the EditText above, the ListView "jumps" up to the bottom of the EditText.

Comment: @G.Lukas check onclick function for EditText. Provide some more information about .xml file and .java file