# Android ListView in Fragment and Tabs

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm an android beginner. 
I know there's another question like mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510550/android-listview-in-fragment) but I need something more explained....

What I want to do is use tabs and fragment + listview:
I want all the tabs with a ListView.

So the question is how can i do that? If I want to put buttons/EditText etc in these ListViews, where do I create the Listeners?

Thank you...

Comment: consider to use http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Mmm I started with Android a week ago and I would like to do things in the standard way right now...

Comment: actionbarsherlok provides you simple way for creating tab. It is just a library.

Comment: Not sure what IDE you're using, but I know that in Eclipse and Android Studio you can create a new project that has Scrollable Tabs + Swipe and then you could just drop a custom list view in. With these examples you'll have to have a min SDK version of 11. If you're targeting an SDK lower then that, then you'll probably have to use some additional, third-party libraries.

Comment: You opened me a world. Tomorrow I will try, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I create a project with Tabs and OK, but what if I want to add ListView to Fragment? I have to put the ListView where? in public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {} ?

Comment: ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WHAT, R.layout.row, myStringArray); What I have to put in WHAT?

Comment: Ok problm solved :D Thanks all