# How to implement a listview into a fragment?

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I am a beginner in android development.
For a project, I would like to know how to implement a listview into a fragment ?

In my project, I have 3 fragments.

I have to retrieve all the contacts which are in my phone.
(I am using this example => http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.fr/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html).
Then, I'll put them into one af the fragment, which contains a listview.

I am searching for many example, but it is only listview into ACTIVITY example.

Can you please help me ?

Best regards,

Tofuw

PS : Sorry for my bad english, I'm french :/

**EDIT**

Here is my code :

```
public class PhoneFrag extends ListFragment
{
private List<Contact>listecontact=new ArrayList<Contact>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState, Context context)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    String[]values=new String[]{};

    Cursor phones=context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

    while(phones.moveToNext())
    {
        String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String num=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        Contact contact=new Contact();
        contact.setName(name);
        contact.setNum(num);

        listecontact.add(contact);
    }
    phones.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, listecontact);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have an error at the third last line :

> the constructor ArrayAdapter(FragmentActivity, int,
>   List) is undefined

Can you help me please ?

Tofuw

Comment: Why not just use a ListFragment? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510550/android-listview-in-fragment

Comment: same as in an Activty. Build your xml. Get A instance of the ListView within its onCreateView(...) with `ListView lv = (ListView)fragmentRootView.findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);` I do not see your problem

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer ! I'm using the ListFragment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get your Fragment to extend `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`.If you have used or looked at examples with `ListActivity` there is no need to associate this fragment with an xml layout file using `setContentView(layout)` anymore,Android creates a readymade `Fragment` with a `ListView` within it for your conveniance.Instead conveniance methods like `setListAdapter(adapter)` are available to you.However,in case you would like to access the `ListView` instance use the `getListView()`.The Fragment seems to use `onActivityCreated` to do this:

I am guessing that you know fragments well enough to understand that `this` in `ListActivity` mean `getActivity()` in your `ListFragment`.

Here is the code that I found in the [Android Fragment Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout):

```
 public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
boolean mDualPane;
int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Populate list with our static array of titles.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES));

    // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
    // fragment directly in the containing UI.
    View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }

    if (mDualPane) {
        // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
        showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    showDetails(position);
}

/**
 * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
 * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
 * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
 */
void showDetails(int index) {
    mCurCheckPosition = index;

    if (mDualPane) {
        // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
        // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
        getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

        // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
        if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
            // Make new fragment to show this selection.
            details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

            // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
            // with this one inside the frame.
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (index == 0) {
                ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
            } else {
                ft.replace(R.id.a_item, details);
            }
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }

    } else {
        // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
        // the dialog fragment with selected text.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

You can also use methods like `setEmptyText` and `setListShown` to display a message in case your Cursor has no rows and toggle the visibility of your listView respectively.Also,Android's Loader Framework is only supported with a Fragment and not an Activity in the support library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user2309862. But now, I have an other problem. Can you help me please ? I'll post my code below, and detail more precisely.